# Auto-refresh PHP display variable

Tags: php, time, refresh

I am needing to automatically refresh my PHP page. I have a PHP page that is returning the current database time. However, this is requiring me to refresh the page in order for me to update.I need a better way of updating this PHP variable that does not include refreshing the page. Here's what I have so far:

```
$time = current_time($db);
echo '<p>$time</p>'
```

How can I accomplish this?
EDIT:
I've changed my code but it still won't auto-refresh:
index.php

```
<div id="#timeLocation">

<script>
var updateTime = function(){
$.ajax({url: "time.php", success: function(response){
$('#timeLocation').html(response);
}});
setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
}

updateTime();

</script>


</div>
```

time.php

```
 <?php 

 require_once('db.php');
 require_once('functions.php');

$time = current_time($db);
echo $time[0];


?>
```

Comment: AJAX is the answer.

Comment: Could you provide a simple example to help me get started? I've read that other people have said AJAX as well but I'm not sure how to incorporate it into my code.

Comment: There are lot's of basic AJAX tutorials online.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 2):

index

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Time</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="time">

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({url: "time.php", success: function(response){
                $('#time').html(response)
            }});
        }, 1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

time.php

```
<?php

$time = date("g:i:s a");
echo $time;
```

this isnt the exact answer but it will help you along the way, watch when using ajax the way ive displayed though, sending a request everysecond could eventually slow down your server with enough time

Answer (score 0):

With javascript you can run a function every tot. second:

```
setInterval(function,60000)
```

The function that you call should be an ajax request to a PHP page, that return the current hour. In my opinion you can implement all with only javascript, calling a function every second that update the hour field.

Answer (score 0):

While ajax has been told in the comments, here is a pseudo implementation of it:

```
<div id="#timeLocation"></div>

<script>
const updateTime = function(){
     $.ajax({url: "time.php", success: function(response){
        $('#timeLocation').html(response);
    }});
    setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
}
updateTime();
</script>
```

This will update the timeLocation div with the content of time.php every second.